# More efficient way of using Import-CSV in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to figure out a more efficient way of using Import-CSV (powershell) to place values into an array of csv files. The problem is that some of these files have several hundred thousand lines and running this script in conjunction with other lines of code is what appears to be a big bottle neck. Do you guys have any suggestions of how to make this code more efficient and faster?

```
foreach($csv in $csvfiles)
{
    $csvname = $csv.name;
    $paygroup = $csvname.substring(4,3);
    $batch = $csvname.substring(14,4);
    write-host "Writing $csvname";
    $csvimportdata = Import-CSV $CurrentPath"\$csvname";
        foreach($record in $csvimportdata)
        {
        $record.chartfield1 = $paygroup;
        $record.chartfield2 = $batch;
        $record.chartfield3 = $record.line_descr.substring(0,6);
        }
    $csvimportdata | Export-CSV $CurrentPath"\$csvname" -NoTypeInformation
};
```

Comment: If you have CSV files with hundreds of thousands of entries, and you have to modify them regularly then my advise is to stop using CSV files and make a SQL database.

Comment: As long as he wants to modify all lines (excluding the header) and the order of the columns are static, he could also rewrite the script to use regex and a foreach-loop.

Answer (score 0):

If your CSVs are large then loading into memory is probably not a good idea. How about something like this:

```
foreach($csv in $csvfiles)
{
    $csvname = $csv.name
    $paygroup = $csvname.substring(4,3)
    $batch = $csvname.substring(14,4)
    write-host "Writing $csvname"

    Get-Content $CurrentPath"\$csvname" -Readcount 1 | % {
      # Regex below assumes a three column CSV
      $_ -replace '^([^,]+,[^,]+,[^,]{6}).*$', '$1'
    } | Set-Content $CurrentPath"\$csvname"
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the Regex. i'm trying to learn what your syntax is doing.

Comment: The regex is based on al lot of assumptions because I don't have an example of your data. How you process your rows of text inside the loop is not the important bit, the main issue that makes your version slow is that you were loading the entire file into memory whereas mine is processing one line at a time. Add some data to your question and I will be able to code something more specific.

Comment: Here is a zip file of my entire script and some example data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c9bi3fcesw670d2/example.zip?dl=0