# PowerShell; Need help import CSV into system.collection.arraylist

Tags: .net, powershell, csv, arraylist

*This question has been restated as a result of the comments by Doug Maurer and Mathias R. Jessen

I am trying to process the .CSV exported files from Nessus compliance and vulnerability scans.  I am combining all the CSV files with the same format and am left with a new CSV file that averages around ~90,000 records and 26 attributes.

I need to:
(1) Remove all the rows that have the string "[PASSED]" in the description attribute
(2a) Consolidated into a single record, all the data in the "Host" attribute of every record with an identical "Description" attribute
(2b) Remove all the records with an identical "Description" attribute; except for the record with the consolidated "Host" attribute

I currently have a solution for this that incorporated Microsoft Excel with PowerShell, but the script took 8 days to run; and I think I can make the process faster by eliminating Excel from the script and just processing the data in a PowerShell object or similar.

I know PowerShell array's are inefficient when it comes the the amount of data I want to process, but I was told [system.collection.arraylist] is vastly more efficient; so I have tried to use the below method to create a multi-dimensional array, but have not been successful.

```
$list=Import-CSV ./MasterCompliance.csv

$array=[System.Collections.ArrayList]@(,($list.'Plugin ID'),($List.CVE),($List.CVSS),($List.Risk),($List.Host),($List.Protocol),($List.Port),($List.Name),($List.Synopsis),($List.Description),($List.Solution),($List.'See Also'),($List.'Plugin Output'),($List.'STIG Severity'),($List.'CVSS v3.0 Base Score'),($List.'CVSS Temporal Score'),($List.'CVSS v3.0 Temporal Score'),($List.'Risk Factor'),($List.BID),($List.XREF),($List.MSKB),($List.'Plugin Publication Date'),($List.'Plugin Modification Date'),($List.Metasploit),($List.'Core Impact'),($List.CANVAS))
```

The above code only makes a single dimension array with 26 records....instead of an array with all of the records and 26 dimensions.

I don't have to stick with arrays, if this would work better with a different object type I would be open to that as well.

Comment: I think you may have an xy problem. In which way are you importing/using that is inefficient?

Comment: If you have 90K rows, you might want to _avoid_ storing them all in memory at once. Agree with @DougMaurer, this sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

The major problem is not the array, the problem is the import-csv here.

You have the following options:

1.) You can try get-content with -readcount and then convertto-csv.

2.) (and probably the most efficient) is using the .net streamreader see e.g. here
https://www.sqlshack.com/reading-file-data-with-powershell/
or
[More efficient way of using Import-CSV in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677211/more-efficient-way-of-using-import-csv-in-powershell)

3.) the use of arraylist works pretty well in powershell and how to work with them e.g. here:
https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-arraylist/

I recomment you to use the .net reader with an array list

Regards